# how to receive binary data from recv winsock function

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

I seek how to receive binary data from HTTP request with recv function of winsock API.

I get no problems to do with std::string and string.append()
but my program need no dependency.

Anyone know how to get the same result just with char* buffers ?

```
    do {
      iRecv = recv(m_socket, recvBuffer, MAX_BUFFER, 0);

      if ( iRecv > 0 )
      {

        //Need to override std::string with pure WINAPI
        response.append(recvBuffer, iRecv);

        iResponseLength += iRecv;
        xZeroMemory(recvBuffer, MAX_BUFFER);

      }
    } while( iRecv > 0 );
```

Comment: `std::string` is well capable of holding binary data, however you might find using `std::vector<uint8_t>` more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good reason NOT to use STL containers, since they are core to C++ so they are going to be available in every C++ compiler.

But, to answer your question, if you *need* to avoid them for whatever reason, you can do something like this:

```
int iResponseCapacity = MAX_BUFFER*5;
int iResponseLength = 0;
char *response = new char[iResponseCapacity];

do
{
      iRecv = recv(m_socket, recvBuffer, MAX_BUFFER, 0);
      if (iRecv <= 0) break;

      if ((iResponseLength + iRecv) > iResponseCapacity)
      {
          int iNewCapacity = iResponseCapacity + (MAX_BUFFER*5);
          char *newResponse = new char[iNewCapacity];
          memcpy(newResponse, response, iResponseLength);
          delete[] response;
          response = newResponse;
          iResponseCapacity = iNewCapacity;
      }

      memcpy(&response[iResponseLength], recvBuffer, iRecv);
      iResponseLength += iRecv;
}
while (true);

//...

delete[] response;
```

The key is to reallocate the `response` buffer each time it fills up to its max capacity.  STL containers like `std::string` and `std::vector` handle this internally for you.  There are plenty of algorithms available to calculate efficient growth increments when reallocating to better maximize memory performance and usage, the above is just a simple example to demonstrate the idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
int bytesRead, iRecv;
char recvBuffer[MAX_BUFFER];

bytesRead = 0;
do {
  iRecv = recv(m_socket, recvBuffer + bytesRead, MAX_BUFFER - bytesRead, 0);
  if ( iRecv > 0 )
     bytesRead += iRecv;
} while ((iRecv > 0) && (bytesRead < MAX_BUFFER));
```

When the do loop completes: `bytesRead` holds the number of bytes read and the data is in `recvBuffer`. If `iRecv` is zero, the connection was normally closed. If `iRecv` is less than zero, there was an error. If `iRecv` is greater than zero, the buffer is full.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not get my data completely
I receive only the value of MAX_BUFFER.

I think I have to copy the contents of recvBuffer while also dynamically increasing the size of the receiver. ?

Comment: @Ett Just call this code as many times as you need to. Or make the buffer larger.